# getting the string path piece by piece with regex (SQL -Athena)

Tags: sql, regex, string, amazon-athena

i want to convert a string into rows in SQL in Amazon Athena

Since Athena not support certain functions im forced doing many regex functions

a input (who can also have different lengths ) can look like this:

```
v1 facility username utm_parameter
```

and i want to turn this into a table who will look like this

```
1st    |  2nd     | 3rd     | 4th
------ | ------   | -----   | -----
v1     | facility |username | utm_parameter
```

i allready filter out the first piece of text out of the string with this code:

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT( REGEXP_replace( REGEXP_REPLACE( REGEXP_EXTRACT( REGEXP_EXTRACT(message,'path=\S+'),'"(.*?)"'),'/', ' '),'"',''),'\S+') AS '1st' from data
```

but i dont know how to get the text part after the next blank spaces with the regex

does anyone know how i write the next regex function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
-- input, don't use in real query
WITH
input(message) AS (
SELECT 'v1 facility username utm_parameter'
)
-- input end, start real query here
SELECT
  SPLIT_PART(message,' ',1) AS "1st"
, SPLIT_PART(message,' ',2) AS "2nd"
, SPLIT_PART(message,' ',3) AS "3rd"
, SPLIT_PART(message,' ',4) AS "4th"
FROM input;

1st|2nd     |3rd     |4th
v1 |facility|username|utm_parameter
```

And, for the rest, it's like spelling the word Mississippi: you need to know when to stop.....